# How to constantly find the x and y position of a moveable element

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
   $(function() {
    
    $.fn.getPosition = function() {
        var results = $(this).position();
        results.right = results.left + $(this).width();
        results.bottom = results.top + $(this).height();
        return results;
    }
    
    $(nWindow).resizable({
        maxWidth: 1356,
        maxHeight: 585.5,
        grid: [ 3, 4 ],
        aspectRatio:true,
        
    });

    $(nWindow).draggable({
        cursor: "move",
        snapTolerance: '20',
        snap:nWindow, 
        containment:container,
        stop: function(e, ui) {
         console.log($(this).attr("id"), $(this).getPosition()); //How do i store these positions into a variable and use it in other functions
        } 

});
```

In the above code, how do i store the values of `this.getposition` that is `left` and `top` into seperate variables so i could use it in other functions, i know i could do it by declaring a global variable and then assigning `.getposition` but i want to constantly keep a track of the div thats being moved and update the variable accordingly, when i assign the variable and try calling it it gives me `null`or `undefined`

Answer (score 1):

try using it like this

```
let postion = {};
$(function() {
    
    $.fn.getPosition = function() {
        var results = $(this).position();
        results.right = results.left + $(this).width();
        results.bottom = results.top + $(this).height();
        postion = {...result}; 
        return results;
    }
    
    $(nWindow).resizable({
        maxWidth: 1356,
        maxHeight: 585.5,
        grid: [ 3, 4 ],
        aspectRatio:true,
        
    });

    $(nWindow).draggable({
        cursor: "move",
        snapTolerance: '20',
        snap:nWindow, 
        containment:container,
        stop: function(e, ui) {
         console.log($(this).attr("id"), $(this).getPosition()); //How do i store these positions into a variable and use it in other functions
        } 

});
```

Comment: Even if i use the on drag event how would i be able to store those values into seperate variables cause ultimately i want to be able to use the same positions in other functions

Comment: You can store these values in variables out side of this function or call those functions from inside the event and pass the position to them

Comment: could you please show me how cause i tried storing it into a variable then returning it after the drag function has stopped but still became null

Comment: im not sure would position keep getting updated? cause i have multiple draggable divs and everytime i move one i wanna be able to check what position it is and create new ones accordingly

Comment: so you can make an array of positions or even better an object with id's of each one you create as a key which holds the position values